# SpriteKit Objective-C – Detect how much finger has moved in -touchesMoved

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, pixel, touchesmoved

I'd simply like to know if there is a way to detect how many pixels the finger has moved during the `-touchesMoved` function?

**EDIT:**

This is what I've tried. I made two instance variables called `_previousPosition` and `_currentPosition`. In `-touchesBegan`, I set them both to be the current finger location in the scene. In `-touchesMoved`, I set `_currentPosition` to be the current finger location once again. Keep in mind that during `-touchesMoved`, when I'm updating `_currentPosition`, `_currentPosition` is being constantly updated, while `_previousPosition` is not. Finally, in `touchesEnded`, I create another variable (not global, but private) called `pixelsMoved`, and set that equal to **_currentPosition - _previousPosition**. Right after that, in `-touchesEnded`, I reset `_previousLocation` to be the current finger location. It's all very complicated, so I'm almost positive I've made some mistake somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd simply like to know if there is a way to detect how many pixels the finger has moved during the -touchesMoved function?

`-touchesMoved:withEvent:` provides an event, and from the event you can get individual touch objects, each of which have an associated location that you get with `-[UITouch locationInView:]`. You don't get information about how far the touch has moved since the last time you looked, but you can keep track of the location of each touch and do the comparison yourself.

Comment: Thank you, Caleb, but that doesn't necessarily answer my question. I need a way to track it, yes. Could you provide me some code? Do I create a global variable and a private variable? Set the private variable to the current position in `-touchesMoved`, and find the difference via subtraction? Something like that?

Comment: How you track it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish, but I'd generally lean toward using an instance variable to store the starting location. You could set that in `touchesBegan:...`. Are you trying to track the total number of pixels moved, or just the distance from the start? Remember that `-touchesMoved:...` will be called repeatedly until the touch ends, but the frequency may vary depending on a number of things, so the distance between any two `-touchesMoved:...` calls doesn't mean much by itself.

Comment: I see what you mean. Let me be more precise. I need to know if the user touched the screen and moved his finger more than 20 pixels **before releasing the screen**. *In other words, when `-touchesEnded` is called, I want to find out how many pixels the finger moved BETWEEN `-touchesBegan` and `-touchesMoved`.* Let me edit my question to add what I've already tried.

Comment: Sounds like you really only care about the difference between -touchedBegan... and -touchesEnded...

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess so. But I'm still confused on exactly how to do it. I'll keep working on it, but it would obviously help if you gave me a solution ;)